# Format any numeric value of a data frame

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
col1 <- c(0.00002, 0.001, 0.5689785541122558)
col2 <- c(3.5, 45.6546548788, 12585.5663)
col3 <- c(200.00, 34.52, NA)
tab_test <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)
```

I would like to format all numbers appropriately by writing a single function. I'm using this code to force scientific notation when numbers are smaller than 0.001

```
formatta_val <- function(x) {
  mapply(format, x, scientific = abs(x) < 0.001, digit = 1, nsmall = 3)
}
replace(tab_test, TRUE, lapply(tab_test, formatta_val))
```

I would like to upgrade `formatta_val()` in order to get the data frame as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2e-05 | 3.5 | 200 |
| 0.001 | 45.65 | 34.52 |
| 0.569 | 12,585.57 |  |

Comment: `data.frame(lapply(tab, formatta_val))`

Comment: `tab_test[] <- lapply(tab_test, formatta_val)` With the square brackets the tabular shape is kept, without them the output is a list.

Comment: @Rui Barradas the code I wrote works perfectly. What I need is adding to formatta_val some other code in order to format integers and big number with thousands separator as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `formatC`. Since `format=` argument isn't binary, some subsetting is needed where we set `NA's` arbitrary to `1L`. We add a `d=`igits argument, whose values are fed into the `Map` as second variable. Your `replace` looks like overkill, `as.data.frame` should be sufficient.

```
formatta_val <- \(x, d) {
  tt <- (abs(x) < 0.001) + 1L
  tt[is.na(tt) | x == 0] <- 1L
  mapply(formatC, x, format=c('f', 'e')[tt], digits=c(d, 0L)[tt], big.mark=',',
         drop0trailing=TRUE)
}

as.data.frame(Map(formatta_val, tab_test, c(3L, 2L, 2L)))
#    col1      col2  col3
# 1 2e-05       3.5   200
# 2 0.001     45.65 34.52
# 3 0.569 12,585.57    NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
tab_test <- structure(list(col1 = c(2e-05, 0.001, 0.568978554112256), col2 = c(3.5, 
45.6546548788, 12585.5663), col3 = c(200, 34.52, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks @jay.sf, it works great but 0 values are turned into 0e+00. How can I leave those unchanged?

Comment: @mbistato Include the test in line 2, see edit.